# About minimal ideals and division rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

From Louis H. Rowen book [Ring Theory](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ring-Theory-83-Louis-Rowen/dp/0125998406), We have this proposition:

[Proposition 2.1.31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVvBl.gif)

My first question:

In the proof, he just showed that every nonzero element has a left inverse but to prove the ring is a division ring we need also to show that every nonzero element has a right inverse. So, why does every nonzero element has a right inverse here?

My second question: in the same book, we have this proposition

[proposition 2.0.16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8s6b.gif)

but I am confused here because the first proposition above stated  that it is possible that there is a division ring with a proper nonzero left ideal but this is a contradiction with proposition 2.0.16 above?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x,y,z \in D$, where $D$ is a ring and $zy=yx=1$ (so that $z$ is a left inverse of $y$, which is in turn a left inverse of $x$). Then, $x=1x=(zy)x=z(yx)=z1=z$, so in fact $xy=yx=1$ and $y$ is then a two-sided inverse of $x$.

In fact, the above argument works in any monoid.

Comment: We know that every element has a left inverse but why did you assume here also that every element is a left inverse element of another element?

Comment: In other words why did you assume here that y also has a right inverse?

Comment: @user130281 it could be started off more clearly:  suppose every nonzero thing be a left inverse, and let $x$ be nonzero. Then it has a nonzero left inverse $y$. Then $y$ has a nonzero left inverse $z$. By the argument above, $x=z$ so that $y$ and $x$ are mutually inverse, hence both invertible.  Thus every nonzero thing has a right inverse as well.

Comment: Thank you for you both. How about the second question?